# zsh: command not found: smbclient error when trying from mac

Tags: mac, smb

How to connect smb (server message block) from mac ??

When I try `smbclient -L <IP>` I get an error message

```
zsh: command not found: smbclient
```

Comment: macOS doesn't have `smbclient` See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/697/how-can-i-mount-an-smb-share-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have figured this out or if it is still usefull to you, but you can install it with: brew install samba.
After that you will have smbclient. :)